# How can I dismiss FBWebDialogs?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, fbwebdialogs

I'm working on one Touch app, in this i have to navigate to one viewController when user presses the home button, irrespective to what ever viewController user is currently seeing.
The problem is , if i open up `FBWebDialogs` using '`presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession`', its not removed from the view.

i already tried to remove all views from the super view, pop to rootviewcontroller and dismissModalViewController but still it stays on screen.

any one has any idea how can I programmatically close it?

Comment: See this answer for a workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21969859/2210889

Comment: Rv15 how did you end up solving this?

Comment: Did u get solutions to your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can refer this one 
http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/Facebook-iOS-SDK/3.7.0/Classes/FBWebDialogs.html 
thanks

Comment: I already have seen this link, its of no use for hiding the FBWebDialogs, they just listed the ways to present it.

Comment: Hi You can also refer FBWebDialogHandler in this links https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBWebDialogs/             hope it can help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the following:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```